# How can I exclude specific authors from wp_list_authors

Tags: theme-development

I want to have the authors listed like usual from `wp_list_authors()` but I know there are a couple of ones I would like to exclude from the list as well.   Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: *@Paul Sheldrake*: Do you *always* want to exclude those users, or only in certain contexts? If only in certain contexts, which ones?

Comment: Typically I would always want to exclude them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wp_list_authors()` now does have an `exclude` parameter. So you can exclude the authors you want by their user ID.

It accepts:

> An array, comma-, or space-separated list of author IDs to include. Default empty.

Examples:

```
// exclude just the author with the ID 4
wp_list_authors([ 'exclude' => 4 ]);


// exclude the authors with the IDs 4 and 7
wp_list_authors([ 'exclude' => [ 4, 7 ] ]);

// or
wp_list_authors([ 'exclude' => '4, 7' ]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems [`wp_list_authors` does not have any filters](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/author-template.php#L269), nor does [`get_users_of_blog`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.0/wp-includes/user.php#L341), the function it uses to get the user list. So you either have to regex-and-replace the output yourself, or create a similar function with an extra parameter to specify authors to exclude. It's not too big, and most of the code is spent handling options, so it isn't that much duplication.

You could always vote for [the existing Trac ticket to get an `exclude` parameter added](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9902) in a future version!

Comment: @EAMann: Ah, you didn't have to delete your answer for this!

Comment: We were saying the same thing.  No reason to duplicate what was already a good answer.

Comment: @EAMann: But the rep man! Think of the rep! Oh, wait - a diamond next to your name. Nevermind. You're *one of those*.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code to include info from Authors (WordPress users) in a page template. It could be reversed to exclude authors.

```
<?php
            //display selected users
            $userids_to_display = array(4,221,22,3,5,9,235,236,250); // wordpress user IDs to include
            $blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
            if ($blogusers) {
              foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
                if ( in_array($bloguser->user_id, $userids_to_display) ) {
                  $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
                  echo '<div>';
                  echo '<div class="alignleft">'.get_avatar($user->ID).'</div>';
                  echo '<div class="user-data"><h3>' . $user->user_firstname . ' ' . $user->user_lastname . '</h3>';
                  echo '<div class="author-description">'.$user->description.'</div>';                
                  echo '</div>';
                }
              }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems there is no way to do this without a custom function, you could use jQuery to find their names and hide them after the list is generated. Something like this:

```
$('ul.author_list li:contains("John")').remove();
```

I also found a plugin that can do this for you:
[List Authors Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-authors-plus/)